# Angular - ActivatedRoute in click event

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-activatedroute

I am using `ActivatedRoute` to call the summary table from one component to another component and I added below I am not able to get the summary table as expected in click event

**tab-routing.module.ts**

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TABMasterComponent } from '../tabs/tab-master/tab-master.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "tabmasters", component: TABMasterComponent,
        loadChildren:'../tabs/tab-master/tab-master.component',
     data:{
       istab : false
     }
     },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**tabmasters.component.ts**

```typescript
istab = false;


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router, private toastr:ToastrService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
      this.istab = this.route.snapshot.data.istab;
      console.log('here',this.route.snapshot.data)
      }
```

**tabmaster.component.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="iscontrol">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="table_header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let cl of ClList;">
                        <td>{{ cl.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="istab">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="table_header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let tab of tabList;">
                        <td>{{ tab.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
</div>
```

I want to show istab summary when I use the click event in app component. but I am facing the problem is these two above table is in tab component and I want to show istab summary only in click event

```
TAB1----isctrl summary              TAB2-----istab summary
```

I used the `boolean` if I click `tab 1` `isctrl` `true` and `istab` `false`  and if I click `tab2` `ista` is `true` and `isctrl` is `false`

the above two summary is in `tabcomponent` which is used to show is bootstrap nav tabs like below tabs

[image: bootstrap tabs]

my **app.component.HTML** is like

```html
<button (click)="gotoTabsUMMARY()"></button>
```

and my **app.component.TS** is like

```typescript
istab = false;


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router, private toastr:ToastrService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
      this.istab = this.route.snapshot.data.istab;
      console.log('here',this.route.snapshot.data)
      }



gotoTabsUMMARY(){
        this.router.navigate(["/tabsmasters"], { skipLocationChange: true, this.istab})
}
```

I want to go to the summary table in click event in app component. normal router link is working but I want to get summary which is in tab2 I used the another method emit is not working How to use `activatedRoute` to this..